Dynamic Font Size Adjustment in Multiline TextField Not Working as Expected
I’m trying to implement a multiline TextField inside a custom sticky note component. My goal is to make sure that the entire text remains visible within the sticky note, and when the text grows, the font size should automatically decrease to fit the available space. However, instead of adjusting the font size, the text continues to scroll up and disappear as more lines are added. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
@State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 16

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            TextField("Notiz", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                .padding()
                .background(Color.clear)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: geometry.size.height - 20, alignment: .leading)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .disabled(false)
                .onChange(of: text) { _ in
                    adjustFontSizeToFit(in: geometry.size)
                }
        }
    }
}

private func adjustFontSizeToFit(in availableSize: CGSize) {
    let maxWidth = availableSize.width
    let maxHeight = availableSize.height
    let textBoundingSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight)

    // Berechne die Größe des Textes basierend auf der aktuellen Schriftgröße
    var textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: textBoundingSize,
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
        context: nil
    ).size

    // Verkleinere die Schriftgröße, bis der gesamte Text in die StickyNote passt
    while (textSize.height > maxHeight || textSize.width > maxWidth) && fontSize > 10 {
        fontSize -= 1
        textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: textBoundingSize,
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
            context: nil
        ).size
    }

    // Vergrößere die Schriftgröße, falls Platz übrig ist
    while textSize.height < maxHeight && textSize.width < maxWidth && fontSize < 16 {
        fontSize += 1
        textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: textBoundingSize,
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
            context: nil
        ).size
    }
}


Your size calculation is not quite correct.
var textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
    with: textBoundingSize,
    options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
    attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
    context: nil
).size

In this case, textSize will be the size of the returned rect, based on how much space the text needs inside the textBoundingSize.
So, on an iPhone 15 Pro, with the keyboard showing:
let maxWidth = availableSize.width     // equals 393
let maxHeight = availableSize.height   // equals 457
let textBoundingSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight)

Suppose our text is "Hallo Welt" ... the resulting textSize will be:
(77.515625, 19.09375)

If we add two lines to the text,
Hallo Welt
A
B

the resulting textSize will be:
(73.328125, 57.28125)

If we add lots and lots of text, to the point where the text height should exceed maxHeight, the resulting textSize.height will reach 439.15625 ... but will never increase.
So, change this line:
let textBoundingSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight)

to:
let textBoundingSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)

Now, .boundingRect(...) will return the actual height needed for all of the text, and you can compare that height to maxHeight.
As a side note, you can also omit the width comparisons:
private func adjustFontSizeToFit(in availableSize: CGSize) {
    let maxWidth = availableSize.width
    let maxHeight = availableSize.height

    // we want to know the actual height needed, restricting the bounding box width
    let textBoundingSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    
    // Berechne die Größe des Textes basierend auf der aktuellen Schriftgröße
    var textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: textBoundingSize,
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
        context: nil
    ).size
    
    // Verkleinere die Schriftgröße, bis der gesamte Text in die StickyNote passt
    while textSize.height > maxHeight && fontSize > 10 {
        fontSize -= 1
        textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: textBoundingSize,
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
            context: nil
        ).size
    }
    
    // Vergrößere die Schriftgröße, falls Platz übrig ist
    while textSize.height < maxHeight && fontSize < 16 {
        fontSize += 1
        textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: textBoundingSize,
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
            context: nil
        ).size
    }

    // for debugging during development
    print("fs:", fontSize)
}

